# Reload meta tag after ajax request - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, meta-tags

How do I reload a specific meta tag (being generated by php) after an Ajax request?

The tag :

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="efca1389c7f2323c875f3197ead688e9206d8835e10ef618e1241faac2dc750e">
```

The method I'm trying in the Ajax success response (which isn't working) :

```
$("meta[name=csrf-token]").load(location.href+" meta[name=csrf-token]>*","");
```

I'm pretty sure I'm selecting it wrong but can't find the correct approach. Can anybody help?

Comment: $('meta[name="csrf-token"]') try this

Comment: No that didn't work.

Comment: is your jQuery loaded correctly or is there any error in console?

Comment: No errors in console. Ended up reverting back to sending the new token in the JSON response and updating the attr in the Ajax success callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `load()` populates the content of the tag you target. This isn't what you want to do. Instead you need to update *an attribute* of the tag, or just replace the entire tag with the updated one you retrieve from an AJAX request.

You can achieve the latter like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: location.href,
  success: function(html) {
    var newMeta = $(html).find('meta[name="csrf-token"]')
    $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').replaceWith(newMeta);
  },
  error: function(x, s, e) {
    console.log('Something went wrong...');
  } 
});
```

Comment: I was doing it this way originally but wanted to prevent the token from being returned in the JSON response . So is this the only way to achieve it then?

Comment: Firstly you're reloading the current page, so the response will be HTML not JSON. Regardless, if you're making a request of any type the token will be visible in the response. If you're concerned about that you should be using SSL and/or encryption. Also note that this is logically the same as `load()`, you're just handling the response in a different manner,

Comment: I meant the JSON response from the function that handles this Ajax request. Right now I'm simply sending back a 200, "OK" response or 403, "Invalid" if the token fails validation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
var metaTag = document.querySelector('[name="csrf-token"]');
metaTag.setAttribute('content', yourNewDescriptionContent);
```

Assuming that the content is the property from the element you want to change.

Comment: Where does `yourNewDescriptionContent` come from? That would seem to be the important factor in the question.

Comment: `yourNewDescriptionContent ` should be the response token generated from php, so you should set it in the ajax success callback.

Comment: probably the `yourNewDescriptionContent` is not the best naming in this situation :) sorry :)